# How to get submitted form data into a dynamically created csv with download button.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Whenever user will submit form data then submitted form data will store in dynamically generated csv and user can able to download that csv.

Comment: After submit form you can get data from database and then generate CSV (download or view). For CSV you can use `csv` library of Ruby and  can you please show some code for better understanding.

Comment: ok. so can you show some code what have you tried for CSV with your form params

Comment: please edit and  write this part of code in your question with proper code indent for better look, in comments no one can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample code to generate `CSV` modify this according to your need I imagine your form params as `params[:user]` when you click on submit it will download csv file.

```
def generate_csv
  cols = []
  values =[]
  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    params[:user].each do |key,value|
      cols << key
      values << value
    end
    csv << cols
    csv << values

    @filename = "data-#{Time.now.to_date.to_s}.csv"  
  end
  send_data(csv_string, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => @filename) 
end
```

post your form to this action.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)